# Wrong favicon URL used when adding article to Writing section of StackOverflow Careers

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, favicon

I doubt anyone else is affected by this, and even I don't really care about the tiny broken image, but if I give you the details you can at least make an informed decision to ignore it.

I added an article from my company blog to the new Writing section on the Careers profile.  The article is at `http://blog.mycompany.com/date/article`.

When this article is fetched, the system also fetches the favicon to display next to the article on my profile.  The favicon on this blog is not in the default location of `/favicon.ico` but StackOverflow is clever enough to respect the link tag:

```
<link href="/images/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" />
```

StackOverflow resolves the absolute location of the favicon as `http://blog.mycompany.com/images/favicon.ico`.  Entirely reasonable but in this case wrong.

The page also includes a `<base>` tag:

```
<base href="http://mycompany.com/" />
```

So all relative URLs, including the favicon, should be resolved against the specified base URL.  The favicon is actually at `http://mycompany.com/images/favicon.ico`

Comment: Can you give me the example you are using? Would like to reproduce it.

Comment: @Matt Any article on http://blog.rectangularsoftware.com/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be all good now - you will have to re-import your writings though so we can grab the right favicon. Thanks for pointing this out!